# Inclusion preserving map between ideal spaces is continuous in the Fell topology

Tags: ideals, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebras with ideal space $\mathcal{I} (A)$ and equip $\mathcal{I} (A)$ with the Fell topology, i.e. the topology generated by the subbase $U_{I}:=\left\{ J\in{\cal I}\left(A\right)\mid I\nsubseteq J\right\}$, $I \in \mathcal{I} (A)$. In [this](https://www.uni-muenster.de/SFB878/publications/files/phpaCTH2N7984.pdf) paper, on page 2, the author states that if $B$ is another $C^*$-algebra and $\varphi: \mathcal{I}(A)\rightarrow \mathcal{I}(B)$ is a function which preserves the inclusion of ideals, then $\varphi$ must be continuous.

Maybe this statement is obvious but I failed to show it rigorously so far. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

I think what they are saying is simply that 
$$
\varphi^{-1}(U_I)=\{H:\ \varphi(H)\in U_I\}
=\{H:\ I\subsetneq\varphi(H)\}
=\{H:\ \varphi^{-1}(I)\subsetneq H\}
=U_{\varphi^{-1}(I)}. 
$$

Comment: But for this recquires that the statement "$I \nsubseteq \varphi (H)$ if and only if $\varphi ^{-1} (I) \nsubseteq H$" holds, right? Is that clear for general ideal-preserving maps?

Comment: You are right, of course. I'm not familiar enough with the paper to see how the assertion is used. I'm guessing they will never use a pure "arbitrary map that preserves ideals", although I may be wrong.

Comment: You are right. They do not speak about arbitrary ideal preserving maps. But if you look at the proof of theorem 2.1 for example, they argue that continuity must hold as the maps they define there are ideal preserving (without mentioning further properties).